# VB asp.net web application not running in web server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've developed a asp.net web application (in vb.net) which is running in locally while I run it through vs 2010. But the problem is while I upload the published web application in web server it shows error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
    </configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
     </system.web>
</configuration>
```

While I set the "mode" attribute to "Off", it is giving me error....

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```

for your information, I am not using the login form (`Login.aspx`). Lastly after trying to off many tags in `web.config` it is giving error that,

`the site.master does not exists`

What should I do ?

It is a simple webpage that saves customer data into mysql database. I have tried it by giving the remote mysql database details in `connectionstring` and it is working.

I have tried to find the solution in web but failed.

Comment: Looks like, on your page, in `Page` derective masterpage is specified

Comment: Like ??? Mean I cannot understand you...

Answer (score 0):

What Uriil was saying is that at the top of your page, you have something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Bill.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApp.Bill" %>
```

Which means the page is looking for a master page, which in your case doesn't exist.  So either change your page to not refer to a master page, or create a site.master.

Comment: Sorry to say, the file `Site.Master` is exists.